# Why this problem is unbounded, even though it's dual is feasible?

Tags: convex-optimization

In this paper, [An Efficient Inexact ABCD Method for Least Squares
Semidefinite Programming](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04278v2.pdf),page 2, there is a problem called, (P):
\begin{align}
P: &\min_{X,s}  && ‎ \frac{1}{2} ‎\Vert X-G\Vert^2‎ +\frac{1}{2} \Vert s-g\Vert^2 ‎\cr‎
&\text{s.t.}\quad ‎‎‎‎‎&& ‎A_{E}(X)= ‎b_{E}\cr‎
&&& ‎A_{I}(X)= s, X\in S^n_+, X\in \mathcal{P},s\in \mathcal{K}
\end{align}‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎
And then defined problem D, it's dual as: 
\begin{align}
D: &\min_{Z,v,S,y_E,y_I,}  && -\langle b_E,y_E\rangle+\delta_{S_+^n}(S)+‎\delta_{\mathcal{P}}^*(-Z)+\delta_{\mathcal{K}}^*(-v)+ \cr&&&\frac{1}{2} ‎\Vert A_E^*y_E+A_I^*y_I+S+Z+G\Vert^2+\frac{1}{2} ‎\Vert g+v-y_I\Vert^2-\frac{1}{2} \Vert G\Vert^2-\frac{1}{2} \Vert g\Vert^2 \cr&&&\delta_{\mathcal{C}}^*(.) = \sup_{W\in \mathcal{C}} \langle . ,W\rangle
\end{align}‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎
Is this dual correct? If it is why, mosek,sdpt3, says it's primal infeasible(unbounded)? what is the constraint to impose $\delta_{\mathcal{P}}^*(-Z)$ and $\delta_{\mathcal{K}}^*(-v)$ in non-projective manner as paper says it's done?